# Is a monarchic confederation possible?

Tags: government, politics, near-future, kingdom

In my world that is set in a future Earth, there is a transcontinental country corresponding to the respective areas of the Fifth French Republic, the United-Kingdom of Great-Britain and Northern Ireland, the Kingdom of Spain, Netherlands, the Portuguese Republic, Germany, the Kingdom of Belgica, the United States of America, and most of their respective former colonies including Haiti, Canada, Ireland, Australia, New-Zealand, Jamaica, South Africa, Hispanic America, Suriname, and Brazil (the former colonies not included are most of Africa, and Republic of India).

There are ten official languages: French, English, Spanish, Dutch, Portuguese, Standard German, Russian, Hindustani, Standard Arabic, and Mandarin Chinese (the reason for the last four is because there are many immigrants that were born in Russia, South Asia, the Arabic World, and China).

But my country is a confederation. However, this is not a republic such as Switzerland, but a monarchy (or should I say a decadarchy). There are decarchs, one by official language. There are over sixty States within the confederation. The estimated human population is over 500 millions.

So, I wonder why a confederation would be a monarchy rather than a republic.

Comment: Confederation can not be a mon-archy by definition.

Comment: Technically, yes, if we are talking about the Holy Roman Empire.

Comment: Questions about the motivations of characters or organizations are inappropriate for this site.

Comment: Could you tell a bit more about how the country came to be? I always recommend adding context to questions, but a list of states/languages isn't useful context here for as far as I can tell. Also, what is your actual question? If this is a feasibility check you need to establish your idea further. If you want to ask for the advantages of a monarchy confederacy, you also need to do more groundwork. If you're looking for a plot or series of events leading up to the formation of this state, well Worldbuilding SE isn't that place for that.

Comment: Is this a confederation of 10 semi-independent kingdoms, or one state (which is presumably not then a confederation) with 10 rulers? And why divide the leaders by language, especially when several of those languages have no particular tie to the areas they're ruling?

Comment: United Arab Emirates is look like a confederation of kingdoms.

Comment: Historically, the [Holy Roman Empire](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holy_Roman_Empire) was a loose confederation of more than 60 states, and the top guy was called an emperor. It endured for a very long time, so that it directly proves that it is possible and may be quite stable. Nowadays, the European Union is a confederation of 27 states; there is no top guy as such in the EU, but some of the member states are kingdoms and grand duchies...

Answer (score 1):

When we look at previous monarchies, they held together many different peoples with different languages. However, the monarchy was established through military conquest. For example, China has many different languages (now called dialects), but the empire was established through conquest. England had Welsh, Scottish, and Irish as languages but the monarchy was forced on those lands. Some might argue that the Roman emperor was forced on Rome through military battles such as the civil wars.

So, if you want a monarch over those countries, figure out how to have the military conquest of those countries.